# How much time will a typical home computer take to perform calculations of millions of digits?

Tags: performance, calculator, precision

I know that machines find it difficult to make calculations involving very large numbers. 
Let's say I want to find square of a million digit number. Will a typical computer give an answer almost instantly? How much time does it take for them to handle million digit calculations?

Also what is the reason for them to be slow in such calculations?
I found some calculator websites which claim that they can do the task instantly. Will a computer become faster if they use the method those websites use?

Comment: Websites use computers to operate. How did you find the time to type in those million-digit numbers? And verify the result of the square?

Comment: This is a loaded question, there is so much that goes into such calculations. The best way to see how long it'll take a specific computer is to do the calculations you're talking about and check the execution time. And what do you mean by `almost instantly`? Do you mean by a human's perspective?

Comment: @Mat I didn't verify it, but the websites claim to do so.

Comment: Don't believe all you read on the internet.

Comment: @Mat I believe that quote was originally from Abraham Lincoln, you should attribute it...

Answer (score 3):

On my PC it takes more than 21 minutes to draw a square root of a number with 1 million digits. See the details below. It should be possible to achieve faster times, but "almost instantly" is probably not feasible without making use of special hardware (like graphics boards with [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/about-cuda) support).

I have written a test program in `C#` to find the runtimes for calculating the square root with [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root_of_a_number). It uses the `System.Numerics` library which features the `BigInteger` class for arbitrary accuracy arithmetic.

The runtime depends on the initial value assumed for the iterative calculation method. To look for the highest non-zero bit of the number turned out to be faster than simply always using `1` as initial value.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Numerics;

namespace akBigSquareRoot
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

            Console.WriteLine(" nDigits  error  iterations  elapsed ");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            for (int nDigits = 10; nDigits <= 1e6; nDigits *= 10)
            {
                //  create a base number with nDigits/2 digits
                BigInteger x = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < nDigits / 2; i++)
                {
                    x *= 10;
                }

                BigInteger square = x * x;

                stopWatch.Restart();
                int iterations;
                BigInteger root = sqrt(square, out iterations);
                stopWatch.Stop();

                BigInteger error = x - root;

                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                    ts.Milliseconds / 10);
                Console.WriteLine("{0,8} {1,6} {2,6}       {3}", nDigits, error, iterations, elapsedTime);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n<end reached>");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static BigInteger sqrt(BigInteger x, out int iterations)
        {
            BigInteger div = BigInteger.One << (bitLength(x) / 2);
            // BigInteger div = 1;
            BigInteger div2 = div;
            BigInteger y;

            // Loop until we hit the same value twice in a row, or wind
            // up alternating.
            iterations = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                iterations++;
                y = (div + (x / div)) >> 1;
                if ((y == div) || (y == div2))
                    return y;
                div2 = div;
                div = y;
            }
        }

        private static int bitLength(BigInteger x) {
            int len = 0;
            do
            {
                len++;
            } while ((x >>= 1) != 0);

            return len;
        }
    }
}
```

The results on a DELL XPS 8300 with Intel Core i7-2600 CPU 3.40 GHz

```
nDigits  error  iterations  elapsed
----------------------------------------
     10      0      4       00:00:00.00
    100      0      7       00:00:00.00
   1000      0     10       00:00:00.00
  10000      0     14       00:00:00.09
 100000      0     17       00:00:09.81
1000000      0     20       00:21:18.38
```

Increasing the number of digits by a factor of 10 results in three additional iterations in the search procedure. But due to the increased bit-length, the search iterations a slowed down substantially.

The computational complexity of calculating square (and higher degree) roots is discussed in a [related post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99421/computational-complexity-of-calculating-the-nth-root-of-a-real-number).